# Were 19th century Austro-Hungarians in Sweden or Swedes in Austria-Hungary (Carpathian Mts)?

Tags: europe, sweden, hungary

I am researching a family that I strongly believe has Carpatho-Rusyn roots, at least on one side. However, I have not been able to find any birth information for any of the children, their parents, or THEIR parents. I've conducted a very thorough search at this point for birth information without any success.

Strangely, I've discovered birth information for 3 individuals that match *perfectly* to this family...IN SWEDEN. Until discovering these birth records there was absolutely NO connection to Sweden, or anywhere outside of present-day Hungary, Ukraine, or Slovakia. None whatsoever. Everything matches - names, years of birth. Just the location is wrong.

Is there a historical reason Austro-Hungarians in the 19th century would have traveled to rural Sweden? (Kalmar, Lönneberga)

Could it have been for work or military, for example?

On the reverse end, would there have been a reason for Swedes to travel to the Carpathian Mountain region?

The male has a surname that isn't striking me as "Swedish" (Almas), while the female has a definite Swedish ring to it.

Could a Swede and an Austro-Hungarian have met somewhere?

I find this so unlikely, but I want to investigate all of the possibilities before I dismiss these records since they fit perfectly.

Comment: Is the birth information from primary Swedish records or from later secondary sources? Could there be a coincidence or mis-interpretation of placenames?

Comment: I'd probably ask for more information, if chrisgeo1976 had logged at least once after posting the question. :rolleyes:

Comment: My father, who is Carpatho Rusin has mysterious Swedish matches on his DNA test. Carpatho Rusin were part eastern Slav intermixed with Romanian. Maybe there are some Saxons as well. Could swedes have joined Saxons migrating east.... Puzzling.

Comment: Note that *Almas* (or, rather, *Almás*) is a Hungarian surname. (It means "with apples, apple-y" or "apple orchard".)

Answer (score 7):

Between 1850 and 1920, there was a large wave of Ashkenazic immigration to Sweden from Russia and Poland, and by 1920, the Jewish population of Sweden had grown to 6,500. Perhaps this could be an explanation.